# Chrome JQuery Not Getting Height Correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress-theming

I'm having a problem with http://taxlienagents.com/ and how it is displaying in Google Chrome. When I open the site in Google Chrome, the center Tab Area seems to cover the main text above it. If you take a look at http://img651.imageshack.us/img651/8869/taxliensite.jpg, you should be able to see what I am talking about versus when opening the site in FireFox. When I debug the site in Chrome the height is automatically set to 58px for some reason, however in FireFox it is set to 397px. I am using

```
setHeight : function (el) {
if (this.options.autoHeight)
this.$content_container.stop(true, true).animate({
height : this.getHeight(el)
}, this.options.animSpeed * 2 / 3, this.options.animation);
},
```

to get the height. I've gotten the site to be as XHTML 1.0 Transitional Compliant as I could, however I am not the original developer and I know that the site has some problems.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first you should've mentioned that this is a Wordpress page :) 
Check your WP version and make sure the plug-in want to use is actually supported from your version. 
Otherwise this bit -

***Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://taxlienagents.com/ from frame with URL http://player.vimeo.com/video/32340130?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0&color=067fc0. Domains, protocols and ports must match.***

causes your problems. But as I've said check your versions first.

If that's your own code, make sure it's in the right place, 'cause after 2 or 3 refreshes I can see your entire content. I mean the bits you can't.

Comment: It's my own code, however I am not sure why it is computing the height to be 58px

Comment: It seems to happen when you open a new Chrome Window and go to the URL. After refreshing once, the site appears fine

Comment: hmm, after some debug minutes I've noticed it's the **iFrame** part which causes bugs. It works after a refresh, because Chrome GETs the request and js can easily get the height. Try to work your way with the example from this fellow - [jQueryiFrame](http://sonspring.com/journal/jquery-iframe-sizing) and see what happens.

Comment: I'm confused with what your telling me to do. Can you clarify?

Comment: What I try to say is use jQuery - something like `$('iframe').load(function() {
  this.style.height =
  this.contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight + 'px';
});` to set the height of the **iFrame**

Comment: So create a new script before the other LeTabs.js and add $('iframe').load(function() { this.style.height = this.contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight + 'px'; });

Comment: I just removed all of the iframes and I was still having the height issue, so I don't think the iframes have anything to do with it

Comment: I think I fixed this. What I did was force the initial tab to have a height using the !important tag. So <div class="le-tabs_content" style="overflow:hidden !important; height:395px !important;">.